# How to avoid auto resize of content in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to not to apply the `auto resize` with some content. When I put `.fillMaxHeight()` in modifier the auto resize gets applied. But I don't want to apply for some content even it is with modifier `.fillMaxHeight()`. I enabled the auto resize by adding the following piece of code into `AndroidManifest.xml` -

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

So, Any way to avoid it ?